# Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0 System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have registered plugin at online crm. My old plugins which are working SDK version 5.0. I created new plugin and its using SKK 6.0 version. Plugin registered successfully. But when I trigger plugin it shows an exception. I forgot how to install the SDK version on online. Please send me the useful solution.

How to register plugin in sandbox mode with new SDK version without affecting old plugins which were using older version of SDK.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.TypeInitializationException:
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error.

Comment: Are you using plugin registration tool or the new visualstudio crm toolkit?